# Display Materialize input fields inside of Card

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have this html *using materialize css*

```
<!-- Sign Up Card row -->
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">

            <span class="card-title"><h3>Sign up to find out more.</h3></span>

              <form class="container">
                <div class="input-field col m6">
                  <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col m6">
                  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
                    Submit <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                  </button>
                </div>

              </form>  

          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End of Sign Up Card row -->
```

Which is giving me this result

[image: card-form]

When I remove the `col m6` classes from the `input-field` divs it shows them correctly within the card but stacked one on top of the other.

How do I achieve having both `divs` **inside** the card and positioned on the same row?

**My UI Design of desired composition of card**
[image: desired card]

**Update**

## Working JSFiddle

Note: Modifying the css itself is undesired and a last resort. The prime solution should use only `materialize css` for which I think I should have been more specific.

Comment: If possible, provide working snippet.

Comment: This appears to be a `float` issue, i would suggest adding a `clearfix` technique to the container (unfamiliar with how material does this)

Comment: Can you post a code snippet codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: Will update question

Comment: Should I remove the `css` tag considering I am looking for a solution using the `materializecss` framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `<div class="row"></div>` to wrap around the `div.col` tags

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5qbrqr4/)

```
 <!-- Sign Up Card row -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12 m12">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title"><h3>Sign up to find out more about Two Lanterns.</h3></span>
                      <form class="container">
                        <div class = "row">

                          <div class="input-field col m6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-field col m6">
                            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
                              Submit <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>


                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- End of Sign Up Card row -->
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!  What threw me off a bit though is I had put "col sm12" in with the form class of "container", and you can't do that I guess.  You can ONLY have the form class be "container", unless there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, replace container block with following code.

```
          <form class="container" style="display: flex">
            <div class="input-field ">
              <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field " style="padding-left:16px">
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
                Submit <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
              </button>
            </div>

          </form>
```